# How to extract account network in Polkadot JS Extension

Tags: polkadot-js-extension

Is there a way to extract the selected network of an account, that is configured through the Polkadot JS Extension, through `accounts.subscribe`?

[image: Account Network]

Answer (score 1):

No directly, but you can get that value.

With the script below you get your accounts with its meta information (as you mentioned):

```js
    import { web3AccountsSubscribe } from '@polkadot/extension-dapp';
    await web3AccountsSubscribe(( injectedAccounts ) => { 
        injectedAccounts.map(( accounts ) => {
            const accountMeta = accounts.meta;
            console.log(accounts.meta);
        })
     });
```

The meta information has this format:

```json
    {
    "genesisHash": "0x91b171bb158e2d3848fa23a9f1c25182fb8e20313b2c1eb49219da7a70ce90c3",
    "name": "testingB",
    "source": "polkadot-js"
    }
```

From here we need the genesisHash because is the hash of the network you are looking for.

You can compare it with this file of genesis strings to get the name of your network: https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/master/packages/networks/src/defaults/genesis.ts

In my example is [Polkadot](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/master/packages/networks/src/defaults/genesis.ts#L97).

If is a network registered in this list (Testnets like Westened from your example are not included): https://github.com/paritytech/ss58-registry/blob/main/ss58-registry.json

You can query all the networks using the [@poladot/networks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polkadot/networks) library and create a function to find the network information of the genesisHash of your account:

```js
    import { allNetworks } from '@polkadot/networks';
    console.log(allNetworks);
```